# How to display information in collect view using exemple/udp-ipv6/udp_client?

Tags: contiki, udpclient, cooja

I want to use the collect view for a Routing Protocol, but it's not working. When I used collect view, it displayed nothing, it was empty, and I couldn't get any information.

[image]

I tried to call and implement the functions of collect like in example/ip6/udp_collect/udp_client, but it didn't work.